# Change queryset of inlineformset_factory [django-extra-views]

Tags: django

I am using django extra views. How do I change the queryset of `product` field in forms? My following code works just fine. But it seems to me messy. Is there any better solution? Thanks

```
from extra_views import FormSetView, ModelFormSetView

class MyCreateView(ModelFormSetView):
    model = MyModel

    def construct_formset(self):
        i = 0
        inline_formsets = super(
            MyCreateView, self).construct_formset()
        for formset in inline_formsets:
            inline_formsets[i].fields[
                'product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(
                site=GetActiveSite(self.request))
            i += 1
        return inline_formsets
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this without using the iterator:

```
...
def construct_formset(self):
    formsets = super(MyCreateView, self).construct_formset()
    for formset in formsets:
        formset.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            site=GetActiveSite(self.request))
    return formsets
```